# Can connect to github.com, but cannot pull

Tags: ssh, git, github

I don't know why this is suddenly happening, I haven't had any issues prior to now. I cannot seem to pull from GitHub. I can connect, the following works:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi kbjr! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But then I try to actually do something, and I get this:

```
$ git pull origin master
ssh: connect to host github-fs114-cp1-prd.iad.github.net. port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am getting this for one of my repositories (cannot push or pull), but not for another. The https://status.github.com/ page says:

```
We are currently experiencing issues with access over ssh for some repositories.
```

so they are aware of the issue.

UPDATE: This problem has now been resolved.